# Cosa significa "conciatetti" in questo passaggio?

Tags: word-meaning

Nel racconto *I ventitré giorni della città di Alba*, di Beppe Fenoglio, ho letto:

> Poi dalla città furon visti correre a cerchio verso un sol punto: era la truppa che si accalcava a consolare i suoi ufficiali che piangevano e mugolavano che si sentivano morire dalla vergogna. E quando gli parve che fossero consolati abbastanza tornarono a rivolgersi alla città e a gridare: – Venduti, bastardi…! – eccetera, ma stavolta un po’ piú sostanziosamente, perché non erano tutti improperi quelli che mandavano, c’erano anche mortaiate che riuscirono a dare in seguito un bel profitto ai **conciatetti** della città.

Ho cercato alla voce "conciare" in parecchi dizionari, ma non capisco il significato della parola "conciatetti" che appare nel brano sopra citato. Potreste spiegarmelo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I [conciatetti](http://www.adnkronos.com/lavoro/professionisti/2015/07/28/conciatetti-altoatesini-compiono-anni_XRr8p6D0evYt2DlwRn5oWP.html) sono artigiani che riparano i tetti delle case o degli edifici in genere.

> Sono i conciatetti altoatesini, custodi di sapienti tecniche per
>   rivestire o riparare le coperture degli immobili.

L'enciclopedia Treccani parlando di conservazione delle opere architettoniche riporta la figura dei [conciatetti](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/conservazione_res-acc2c287-dd6c-11e6-add6-00271042e8d9_%28Enciclopedia-Italiana%29/).

[image: Conciatetti]

Comment: Adesso capisco: pensavo fosse qualche sorta di diminutivo di "conciato"!

Comment: No, dovrebbe invece avere a che fare con il racconciatore, cioè colui che racconcia, ripara.

Comment: Sì, grazie, @abarisone, ho capito.